# Installing weinre gives me some error

Tags: node.js, weinre

I am trying to install weinre in windows 7 through windows powershell using the command **`npm install -g weinre`** after downloading node js, but it is throwing following error

```
PS C:\windows\system32> npm install -g weinre
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node
tall" "-g" "weinre"
npm ERR! node v6.10.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code EAI_AGAIN
npm ERR! errno EAI_AGAIN
npm ERR! syscall getaddrinfo

npm ERR! getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.npmjs.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issue

npm ERR! Please include the following file wit
npm ERR!     C:\windows\system32\npm-debug.log
```

[Please click here for the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tpTrH.png)

Comment: Seems like You're​ behind proxy or because of some restrictions DNS server cannot resolve ip address of npm registry.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a blog post discussing problems with EAI_AGAIN - appears that it's usually some kind of network issue on your machine: http://www.codingdefined.com/2015/06/nodejs-error-errno-eaiagain.html